# How do I add a column to large sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table in production that has millions of rows, and it turns out that I need to add a column to it. Or, to be more accurate, I need to add a field to the entity that the table represents.

Syntactically this isn't a problem, and if the table didn't have so many rows and wasn't in production, this would be easy.

Really what I'm after is the course of action. There are plenty of websites out there with extremely large tables, and they must add fields from time to time. How do they do it without substantial downtime?

One thing I should add, I did not want the column to allow nulls, which would mean that I'd need to have a default value.

So I either need to figure out how to add a column with a default value in a timely manner, or I need to figure out a way to update the column at a later time and then set the column to not allow nulls.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD
  newcolumn int NULL
GO
```

should not take that long... What takes a long time is to insert columns in the middle of other columns... b/c then the engine needs to create a new table and copy the data to the new table.

Comment: You know what, you're right. As long as the column has a value of NULL, then it gets added pretty fast. But if I get a default value, its take a long long time. So the real issue I need to plan for is how to add a default value to the column.

Comment: Add the column and then perform relatively small UPDATE batches to populate the column with a default value.  That should prevent any noticeable slowdowns.

Comment: Thanks Agent_9191, that seems like a pretty decent approach.

Comment: Maybe this is nitpicking, but I believe the that "b/c then the engine needs to create a new table and copy the data to the new table" is not entirely accurate. AFAIK, the database engine does not allow "inserting" columns, only adding of columns to the end of the table definition. The client tools are responsible for creating a temp table, copying etc.

Comment: Kim, yes.. i didnt mean to say that the engine does it (even though that's what I wrote :-) ). It's the client tool.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was accepted when the asker explicitly says he wants to have a default value.

Comment: The approach is not working if the new column is part of the primary key

Answer (score 16):

> I did not want the column to allow nulls, which would mean that I'd need to have a default value.

Adding a `NOT NULL` column with a `DEFAULT` Constraint to a table of any number of rows (even billions) became *a lot* easier starting in SQL Server 2012 (but only for Enterprise Edition) as they allowed it to be an Online operation (in most cases) where, for existing rows, the value will be read from meta-data and not actually stored in the row until the row is updated, or clustered index is rebuilt. Rather than paraphrase any more, here is the relevant section from the MSDN page for [ALTER TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx):

> **Adding NOT NULL Columns as an Online Operation**
>
> Starting with SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, adding a NOT NULL column with a default value is an online operation when the default value is a *runtime constant*. This means that the operation is completed almost instantaneously regardless of the number of rows in the table. This is because the existing rows in the table are not updated during the operation; instead, the default value is stored only in the metadata of the table and the value is looked up as needed in queries that access these rows. This behavior is automatic; no additional syntax is required to implement the online operation beyond the ADD COLUMN syntax. A runtime constant is an expression that produces the same value at runtime for each row in the table regardless of its determinism. For example, the constant expression "My temporary data", or the system function GETUTCDATETIME() are runtime constants. In contrast, the functions NEWID() or NEWSEQUENTIALID() are not runtime constants because a unique value is produced for each row in the table. Adding a NOT NULL column with a default value that is not a runtime constant is always performed offline and an exclusive (SCH-M) lock is acquired for the duration of the operation.
>
> While the existing rows reference the value stored in metadata, the default value is stored on the row for any new rows that are inserted and do not specify another value for the column. The default value stored in metadata is moved to an existing row when the row is updated (even if the actual column is not specified in the UPDATE statement), or if the table or clustered index is rebuilt.
>
> Columns of type **varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, text, ntext, image, hierarchyid, geometry, geography**, or CLR UDTS, cannot be added in an online operation. A column cannot be added online if doing so causes the maximum possible row size to exceed the 8,060 byte limit. The column is added as an offline operation in this case.

Comment: What about a null column SQL Server 2012 standard edition 14M rows, 24x7 high concurrency? Will it be a noticeable downtime due to schema lock?

Comment: @Horaciux A `NULL` column instead of `NOT NULL`? If I am understanding that correctly, that is a non-issue. It is meta-data only and is rather instantaneous. Prior to SQL Server 2012 coming out with the ability to add a `NULL` column instantly so long as it has a default value, the only way to add a column without blocking anything was by adding it as `NULL`. But then you had to populate it via SQL Agent job o do sets of 3000 rows per each UPDATE (to avoid lock escalation). So no, you don't need to worry about a `NULL` column, at least not in my experience.

Answer (score 14):

The only real solution for continuous uptime is **redundancy**.

I acknowledge @Nestor's answer that adding a new column shouldn't take long in SQL Server, but nevertheless, it could still be an outage that is not acceptable on a production system.  An alternative is to make the change in a parallel system, and then once the operation is complete, swap the new for the old.

For example, if you need to add a column, you may create a copy of the table, then add the column to that copy, and then use [`sp_rename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) to move the old table aside and the new table into place.

If you have referential integrity constraints pointing to this table, this can make the swap even more tricky.  You probably have to drop the constraints briefly as you swap the tables.

For some kinds of complex upgrades, you could completely duplicate the database on a separate server host.  Once that's ready, just swap the DNS entries for the two servers and voilà!

> I supported a stock exchange company
>   in the 1990's who ran three duplicate
>   database servers at all times.  That
>   way they could implement upgrades on
>   one server, while retaining one
>   production server and one failover
>   server.  Their operations had a
>   standard procedure of rotating the
>   three machines through production,
>   failover, and maintenance roles *every
>   day*.  When they needed to upgrade
>   hardware, software, or alter the
>   database schema, it took three days to
>   propagate the change through their
>   servers, but they could do it with no
>   interruption in service.  All thanks
>   to redundancy.

Comment: How did you catch up on missed transactions during maintenance? Standard replication?

Comment: A stock exchange doesn't need to operate 24/7.  They close at the bell.

Comment: Doh :-)  Thoughts on how to handle that for 24/7 systems?

Comment: Right; this has to be solved by synchronizing the delta of data.  Replication and logging are common solutions.  That's a pretty broad subject though.  My general point is that high-availability and redundancy go hand in hand.

Comment: Well, this is what SSMS does when you generate changes script instead of saving on the tool and wait for action to complete.

Answer (score 9):

> "Add the column and then perform relatively small UPDATE batches to populate the column with a default value. That should prevent any noticeable slowdowns"

And after that you have to set the column to NOT NULL which will fire off in one big transaction.  So everything will run really fast until you do that so you have probably gained very little really.  I only know this from first hand experience.

You might want to rename the current table from X to Y.  You can do this with this command sp_RENAME '[OldTableName]' , '[NewTableName]'.

Recreate the new table as X with the new column set to NOT NULL and then batch insert from Y to X and include a default value either in your insert for the new column or placing a default value on the new column when you recreate table X.

I have done this type of change on a table with hundreds of millions of rows. It still took over an hour, but it didn't blow out our trans log. When I tried to just change the column to NOT NULL with all the data in the table it took over 20 hours before I killed the process.

Have you tested just adding a column filling it with data and setting the column to NOT NULL?

So in the end I don't think there's a magic bullet.

Answer (score 3):

select into a new table and rename. Example, Adding column i to table A:

```
select *, 1 as i
into A_tmp
from A_tbl

//Add any indexes here

exec sp_rename 'A_tbl', 'A_old'
exec sp_rename 'A_tmp', 'A_tbl'
```

Should be fast and won't touch your transaction log like inserting in batches might.
(I just did this today w/ a 70 million row table in < 2 min).

You can wrap it in a transaction if you need it to be an online operation (something might change in the table between the select into and the renames).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this. You insert into `A_tmp` from `A_tbl`. But then you rename from `A_tbl` to `A_old` and then rename `A_old` to `A_tbl`. Shouldn't the last rename be from `A_tmp` to `A_tbl`?

Comment: @Junto yes, i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Another technique is to add the column to a new related table (Assume a one-to-one relationship which you can enforce by giving the FK a unique index). You can then populate this in batches and then you can add the join to this table wherever you want the data to appear. Note I would only consider this for a column that I would not want to use in every query on the original table or if the record width of my original table was getting too large or if I was adding several columns.