# How add defaults values to existing rows while using GETDATE() and SUSER_SNAME() for newly added data in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table with data. I need to add two new columns `author` and `time_ct`. I ran this query for adding the data. My expectation is to add `0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000000` and `not_set` to existing rows.

```
ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ADD [time_ct] DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authi DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000000';

ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ADD [author] VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authii DEFAULT 'not_set';
```

The I added these lines of T-SQL, to use `GETDATE()` and `SUSER_SNAME()` for new rows:

```
ALTER TABLE [ss_auth]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_ss_auth5] DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [time_ct];
ALTER TABLE [ss_auth]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_pss_auth6] DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME() FOR [author];
```

Once I run these queries, I am getting this error:

> Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.

When I run this query it executes without error:

```
ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ADD [time_ct] DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authi DEFAULT GETDATE();
ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ADD [author] VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authii DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME();
```

I need to know how can I add "0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000000" and "not_set" for existing rows?

Comment: The error *is* telling you the problem. When you `ADD`ed `time_ct` and `author` to your table you defined a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` for both (`DF_ss_authi` and `DF_ss_authii`). You will need to `DROP` the existing `DEFAULT` constraints first if you want to assign a new one.

Comment: Depending on the edition, and the row count, that might not be the most performant option, @marc_s . In Enterprise a `DEFAULT` value defined with a new column doesn't require writing every single row.

Comment: @Larnu: what kind of row count is needed before this becomes a problem? (just curious)

Comment: I couldn't give a specific, but enough for me to notice the difference in our Dev and Live environments, @marc_s , as we only have a Standard Licence, but Dev is effectively Enterprise. It does, however, move the point of writing to when the row is updated, so if the OP is likely to be updating all those rows at a later date, then doing the `UPDATE` upfront might be the "better" option. I'm trying to find a question that discusses the differences (I'm sure I'm read one on [dba.se] in the past).

Comment: A relevant answer on the topic here, however, which quotes the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39005281/2029983); Microsoft actually states that with a `DEFAULT` value on enterprise the change should be *"almost instantaneously regardless of the number of rows"* so that would mean even with thousands of rows, you could start to see the difference (even if that's just meer milliseconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Enterprise (or developer) then use a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` at the time you create the column will likely be the better choice (especially if you're unlikely to need to `UPDATE` the existing rows in the future), as this change is performed online (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39005281/2029983) from [Solomon Rutzky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577765/solomon-rutzky) for some discussion). Then, after you `ALTER` the table to `ADD` the new columns, `DROP` the constraint and then add the new one:

```sql
--Add new not-NULL columns with default value
ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
ADD [time_ct] datetime2(7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authi
                                    DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000000';

ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
ADD [author] varchar(200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authii
                                   DEFAULT 'not_set';
GO
--Drop named constraints for initial values
ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authi;
ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authii;
GO
--Add new default constraints
ALTER TABLE tpsone.[ss_auth]
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_ss_auth5]
    DEFAULT GETDATE()FOR [time_ct];
ALTER TABLE tpsone.[ss_auth]
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_pss_auth6]
    DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME()FOR [author];
```

If you are, however, going to be doing lots of `UPDATE`s against the existing rows, then using [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75614265/2029983) may be the better option; as although it result in an "offline" process (locks the table), the cost of adding the values to all the rows is "paid up front". As such, it depends on your and the business' needs.

Comment: I've never tested it, but does the metadata-only for `DEFAULT` also apply if you drop the constraint later and create a new `DEFAULT` for new rows.

Comment: I admit I did not test it here, but sometjing in the back of my mind said it does, @Charlieface . I'll test when I can to validate though.

Comment: @Charlieface sorry that took longer than I expected. Did some quick testing, and yes the metadata-only update appears to still apply.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder how the engine keeps track of it.

Comment: I wouldn't like to guess, @Charlieface . Perhaps a question for [dba.se], as I'm sure someone over there knows. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the default constraints only for new rows - the existing rows will get new columns with NULL - just use a simple UPDATE against your table to update all existing rows to the values you want to use for existing rows...

**Step 1**: add columns as **nullable**:

```
ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ADD [time_ct] DATETIME2 (7) NULL; 

ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ADD [author] VARCHAR (200) NULL;
```

**Step 2**: update the table to get new values into those columns

```
UPDATE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
SET [author] = 'not-set',
    [time_ct] = '0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000000';
```

**Step 3**: alter the column definitions to be `NOT NULL` and add the default constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ALTER COLUMN [time_ct] DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL; 

ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ALTER COLUMN [author] VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authi DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [time_ct];

ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ss_authii DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME() FOR [author];
```

Comment: as you mentioed in the step 3, we have to ALTER COLUMN rather than ADD as below. Please correct me if i am wrong, ```ALTER TABLE [tpsone].[ss_auth]
    ALTER COLUMN [time_ct] DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL;```

Comment: @jaxij: that's the "copy&paste hell" - of course - you're totally right - corrected my response