# How to check if enable/disable keys work?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, bulkinsert

I have a table with an indexed `varchar(256)` column.

For faster bulk insert, I disabled keys, insert more than 10 million entries, and then re-enable the keys after insertion is done.

Surprisingly, the enable/disable keys **took no time**:

```
mysql> alter table xxx disable keys;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table xxx enable keys;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

How do I ensure that enable/disable keys were working properly?

Comment: What is that '1 warning' the console tells you about?

Comment: Is the indexed column `UNIQUE`?

Comment: @9000: where can I view the warning?  can't find it in /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.err

Comment: @Scrum Meister:  at first it was unique, then I deleted the index and recreated it to make it non-unique, but still disable and enabling keys took 0 seconds(even after I inserted 8 million rows, enabling keys took 0 seconds).

Comment: [`show warnings`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html) on mysql console should work.

Comment: it looks like innodb doesn't support enable/disable keys,  how can this be??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you guessed, InnoDB does not support DISABLE/ENABLE KEYS. The warning you got is:

> code 1031 - Table storage engine for
>   'table_name' doesn't have this option

As you can see [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5187).
To see the warning yourself, run `SHOW WARNINGS;` after you run the `ALTER`.

Answer (score 7):

To check if your keys are enabled/disabled, run:

```
show keys in table_name
```

> ```
> +----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------+
> | Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment  | Index_comment |
> +----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------+
> | table123 |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |          |               |
> | table123 |          1 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      | disabled |               |
> +----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------+
> ```

If the key is disabled, the `Comment` column will show `disabled`. If it's enabled, the column will be empty:

> [`Comment` column shows] information about the index not described in its own column, such as `disabled` if the index is disabled. [➫➫➫](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html)

Comment: In what contorted engine/version and how was this achieved? :p