# PHP - Insert Into mysql multiple rows best approach

Tags: php, mysql, insert, row

Ok, so let`s presume I have 3 sql tables and a text file.
Text file is in CSV format.
File structure - imagine a array for each line. Value 0 timestamp; 1,4,7,10 values for tab 1; 2,5,8,11 values for tab 2; 3,6,9,12 values for tab 3.
What is the best approach for inserting data after processing into db? 
Solution 1. foreach line read "insert into tab ... ;" which I currently use and it takes a lot of time.
Solution 2. foreach line read push the sql statement into an array, and when I have all the lines processed make a string like "Insert into tab...; insert into tab...; insert into tab...;" and execute the query.
File has aprox. 4000 lines and I have 7 values for each table.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're asking for code, correct?

Comment: No, I am not asking for code. I am asking for the best approach. Either send the data to sql as each line is read and processed, either make an array for each with the sql statement and then make a string from all the array elements and send the query to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You should use batch inserts instead of doing one record for each statement. In your case, There should be one insert statement for each table (unless there are more records for a given table than can fit in one "mysql packet").

See: [How to do a batch insert in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql)

If you use batch inserts, you should ensure that each batch insert doesn't exceed the [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) variable.

You may also find that indexes are you biggest bottleneck. Disabling them before and reenabling them after a large insert may help. See: [How to disable index in innodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524938/how-to-disable-index-in-innodb)

Lastly, MySQL can have [this technique](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Rb85cOXTKU) applied to it, for high bandwidth insertion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use MYSQL syntax

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file' INTO TABLE tbl_name
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html