# How to disable index in innodb in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, innodb

My `mysql` version is `8.0`. I have an `InnoDB table` with more than `10 million rows` of data, and the data `file size` is `2G`.

I am using `pd.to_sql` to insert `several thousand rows` of data each time. When the `index` is enabled, the insertion speed is `very slow`.

How to `temporarily disable` the `index`? And after the insertion is complete, `enable the index`?

I tried the operation in [How to disable index in innodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524938/how-to-disable-index-in-innodb):

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

But the index is `still` valid.

Comment: *How to temporarily disable the index?* Noway. You may drop the index and recreate it after insertion completed. PS. Primary key (which is clustered) must be stored anycase - if you drop it with another indices then complete table rewriting will occur during its re-creation.

Comment: It seems that only this method is feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, something else is going wrong.

Please provide more details of the code involved.  Inserting a few thousand rows in a 10M-row table will not benefit from the high cost of rebuilding the index.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the indexes.  `UNIQUE` indexes are handled differently.  `FOREIGN KEYs` add overhead.  Batching the rows helps a lot, but 10K rows is on the high-end of what is efficient.  What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Are the rows being inserted in any predictable order?

Comment: I made a comparison, inserting a few thousand rows does not need to delete the index.

Answer (score 3):

1. Drop the index
2. Insert your data
3. Create your index

Comment: Not applicable to primary key or the index which is treated as primary.

Comment: I predict this to be slower than simply inserting the rows -- since it is only 0.1% of the total.