# MySql adding new column results in Too many connections

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is MySQL runs into a 'Too many connections' error when I add a new column to my live database.

The database has 1 million records so it takes a while to add this.

- What is the reason the table locks?
- What to do to keep table running?

The query I execute on the table with 1 million records (InnoDB)

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD COLUMN new_table_column INT(11) NULL 
DEFAULT NULL ;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `show processlist;` to see what the connections are. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

I would also take a look at you mysql configuration as well, specifically checking the max_connections setting. Changing that setting will require a mysql server restart.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html

InnoDB requires a table lock, there isn't much you can do about that.

Take a look at these for some ideas on how to do this:

[Optimizing MySQL for ALTER TABLE of InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654594/optimizing-mysql-for-alter-table-of-innodb)

and

[ALTER TABLE without locking the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463677/alter-table-without-locking-the-table)

Comment: Thanks for you answer and for the links. I think it's not the good option to reach the maximum of connections of MySQL, you will run into the same problem pretty fast (I guess). Thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

mysql is notoriously slow at adding columns.

As far as I know, all databases lock the table while adding columns, because they are changing the layout on disk and it requires heavy I/O.

Often, it is so slow (especially with mysql), the way it's done in production is to create a new table with the extra column, copy the data across, renamed the tables and start using the new table. You of course would stop write-access while you did this, but it's much faster to get the job done.

Comment: Yes, I think there is not really another kind of solution to keep the tables alive in a process like this. Thanks for the answer!